# Debug Network Extension

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, networkextension

I have added NEPacketTunnelProvider extension in my app to connect openvpn but connection status is disconnected without any error. Now i want to debug the extension using breakpoints but my breakpoints not called in extension , i already do lot of R&D on google but no success.

```
    self.providerManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            // Handle an occured error
            print(error)
            return
        }

        do {
            try self.providerManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
        } catch {
            // Handle an occured error
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: please help me ........................

Comment: You could try to attach to running process: `Xcode->Debug->Attach to Process by PID or Name` and enter extension's `Display Name`

Comment: **This question has already an answer at: [How to debug an iOS extension (.appex)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524051/how-to-debug-an-ios-extension-appex)**